# View collation in Couchdb keeping key selection

Tags: mapreduce, couchdb

If I have a CouchDB of status updates:

```
{
  username: "JP",
  update: "Confused by CouchDB",
  updated_at: 2013-05-10T08:30:00Z
}

{
  username: "JP",
  update: "Blissfully unaware",
  updated_at: 2012-05-09T08:30:00Z
}

{
  username: "Bob",
  update: "Talking nonsense",
  updated_at: 2013-04-07T22:15:00Z
}
```

**I'd like to retrieve JP's latest update.**

1. I know I can create a map function like this to select all JP's updates:

   ```
   function(doc) {
     emit(doc.username,doc);
   }
   ```

   Then query with `_view/by_username?key="JP"` - but I then have to sort the output myself to find the one with the most recent date.
2. I know I can create a map function like this to order by date and username:

   ```
   function(doc) {
     emit([doc.username, doc.updated_at],doc);
   }
   ```

   But then I would need to know the time of the update to request the updates by JP (as far as I know, there's no `_view/by_username?key=["JP",*]` type request, which would match anything)
3. I have tried using a reduce function on top of (1) above that looks like this:

   ```
   function (keys, values, rereduce) {
     var latest;

     for(var a in keys) {
         if (latest === undefined || new Date(values[a].updated_at).getTime() > new Date(latest.updated_at).getTime()) {
           latest = values[a];
         }
     }

     return latest;
   }
   ```

   But because the documents I'm storing are actually quite large, I get the "not reducing fast enough" error - my reduce function is outputting about half the data that goes in (ie. two incoming documents become one outgoing document), which apparently is enough to trigger the warning message.

I feel like I'm missing something here - anyone able to help me out?

Answer (score 0):

I maaaay have just answered my own question.

The error occurs when the output of a reduce function is big in comparison to the input. On databases with an odd number of documents there must be a reduce done where the input is only a single document - which of course will entail the output being the same size as the input: error.

If I change the reduce function in (3) to only emit the document id, then I don't trigger the error:

```
function (keys, values, rereduce) {
  var latest;

 for(var a in keys) {
      if (latest === undefined || new Date(values[a].updated_at).getTime() > new Date(latest.updated_at).getTime()) {
        latest = {"_id": values[a]._id};
      }
  }

  return latest;
}
```

But you can't request `include_docs=true` on reduced views (despite [#COUCHDB-914](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/COUCHDB-914) three years back!) so a separate request must be made to retrieve the document details. This really holds back my use case, so I'm still looking for a better answer.

Comment: how about including exactly the document fields that you need? Do you really need all of them?

Comment: Sadly yes, I'm building a kind of admin page showing all the data attached to that status update. I could put dummy data in every status update just to remove for this but that just seems *wrong*.